How to read VISA response string to the end?
I am trying to query my device using Visa
using NationalInstruments.Visa;

Session.RawIO.Write("C1:INSP? 'WAVEDESC'");
string result = Session.RawIO.ReadString().Trim();

It appears by default reading buffer size is 1024 bytes, so if the response is more than that, I need to read more. I don't know how much more I should read and if I read more than in the device buffer, I will have timeout exception. How can I read all data in chunks and without exception?

You can defined the max buffer size like Session.RawIO.ReadString(Int64 count)

@user25009716 but since the data may be very large in some cases, I would like to know how to read it chunked and without exception.
